# Can I marry my mother's cousin sister?

Tags: nikah

I want to know is it permissible in Islam to marry my mother's cousin (sister)? Please give some references.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit?

Comment: You can, but your Jean and her Jean should not be the same.

Comment: The linked duplicate lists all the women that you are forbidden to marry. Anyone else is permissible to marry. Since mother's cousin is not listed it is permitted to marry her based on blood relation alone. You just need to ensure that she is not forbidden due to e.g. suckling.